# PHP FormMail - change time from 24 hour to 12 hour

Tags: php, forms, formmail

I'm using tectite's FormMail PHP file to generate an emailing form for a client. Everything is working great and this is an awesome free script to anyone who is interested. Problem is, they can't understand 24 hour clocks for `input type="time"` so I need to switch things to a 12 hour format

I readily admit I am unfamiliar with PHP but have tried to do my homework in the matter. I've located the following in the file

```
    case 'hour120':     // hour of day (01-12) with possible leading zero
    $s_value = date('h',$lNow);
    break;
case 'hour240':     // hour of day (00-23) with possible leading zero
    $s_value = date('H',$lNow);
    break;
case 'hour12':      // hour of day (1-12) with no leading zero
    $s_value = date('g',$lNow);
    break;
case 'hour24':      // hour of day (0-23) with no leading zero
    $s_value = date('G',$lNow);
```

### break;

```
 function ValueSpec($s_spec,$a_form_data,&$a_errors)
{
global  $lNow;

$s_value = "";
switch (trim($s_spec))
{
case 'date':        // "standard" date format: DD-MMM-YYYY
    $s_value = date('d-M-Y',$lNow);
    break;
case 'time':        // "standard" time format: HH:MM:SS
    $s_value = date('H:i:s',$lNow);
    break;
case 'ampm':        // am or pm
```

I know that `hour120` is my end goal, but I am not sure how to make that the active format as opposed to the current `hour24`

It looks like I can derive a time from the entered field using something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="derive_fields" value="120 = %120%" />
```

but I'm unsure how to link this to my input time fields.

I appreciate any input (no pun intended) you can provide! Thanks very much for your time! -BR

Comment: _“but I am not sure how to make that the active format as opposed to the current hour24”_ – and how are we supposed to know that when we barely know _anything_ about the “free script” that you are using …?

Comment: Very valid point. Sorry, but very unfamiliar with PHP. I've tried to include any reference to Time in the code. Just edited in another section.

Comment: " link this to my input time fields. " Expand on this please.

Comment: For example, how do I tell the code to take information from `input type="time" id="time"` and change the format to a 12 hour clock from 24.

Comment: You could do this server side, get the input when the form has been submitted, then perform the conversion before saving it?

Comment: Using PHP or can I do that with the derived input in the HTML?